# initialise array of dictionaries in swift giving error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am facing weird behaviour in swift. I have

```
let valueOne: [String: String] = [
    "title": "May 29th",
    "value": "260"
]

let valueTwo = [
    "title": "April 24th",
    "value": "260"
]

var historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]
```

But this is giving me a compiler error that

> xxxController.type does not have a member named 'valueOne'

And when I try

```
let valueOne: [String: String] = [
    "title": "May 29th",
    "value": "260"
]

let valueTwo = [
    "title": "April 24th",
    "value": "260"
]

var historyData = [
    [
        "title": "May 29th",
        "value": "260"
    ],
    [
        "title": "April 24th",
        "value": "260"
    ]
]
```

It is working fine no error. Also when I try both codes in Playground, they are working fine.

My question is what I am doing wrong in first snippet?

Comment: You need to declare your code inside a method of your class. Your syntax is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing like:

```
class xxxController: UIViewController {

    let valueOne: [String: String] = [
        "title": "May 29th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    let valueTwo = [
        "title": "April 24th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    var historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]

    // ....
}
```

You can't do this, because we cannot reference *instance* properties in `class` declaration.

Instead, in this case, you should make them `static` properties:

```
class xxxController: UIViewController {

    static let valueOne: [String: String] = [
        "title": "May 29th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    static let valueTwo = [
        "title": "April 24th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    var historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]

    // ....
}
```

Or initialize `historyData` in the initializers:

```
class xxxController: UIViewController {

    let valueOne: [String: String] = [
        "title": "May 29th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    let valueTwo = [
        "title": "April 24th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    var historyData:[[String: String]]

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // ....
}
```

OR make `historyData` as `[[String: String]]!` and assign to it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
class xxxController: UIViewController {

    let valueOne: [String: String] = [
        "title": "May 29th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    let valueTwo = [
        "title": "April 24th",
        "value": "260"
    ]

    var historyData:[[String: String]]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        historyData = [valueOne, valueTwo]
    }

    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but **make sure** that you are writing your snippet inside some method. e.g `viewDidLoad()`.